# WebAPI POST request parameters are null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to do a POST request of a json object and convert it into a class but it's not working. Here's the JS that's sending the object:

```
var TheAjaxData = {
    'Property1': 'TheValue1',
    'Property2': 'TheValue2',
    'Property3': 'TheValue3'
}

$.ajax({
    url: "/thewebapi/themethod",
    type: "POST",
    data: TheAjaxData,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (msg, textStatus, request) {
        console.log(msg);
    }
});
```

The WebAPI receives the request so I know the routing is correct but `TheObject` is null. This is the code:

```
[RoutePrefix("thewebapi")]
public class TheWebAPIController : ApiController
{
    [Route("themethod")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] TheRequestObjectModel TheObject)
    {
        var testvalue = TheObject.Property1;
    }

    public class TheRequestObjectModel
    {
        public string Property1 { get; set; }
        public string Property2 { get; set; }
        public string Property3 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This needs to work with a POST, not a GET. I'm pretty sure I'm close but it's not working. What do I need to change to get the object I'm sending converted into `TheRequestObjectModel`?

Comment: you need to stringify the payload `data: JSON.stringify(TheAjaxData)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to convert your js object into json (as json formats your data in an object):

```
var TheAjaxData = {
    'Property1': 'TheValue1',
    'Property2': 'TheValue2',
    'Property3': 'TheValue3'
}

$.ajax({
    url: "/thewebapi/themethod",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(TheAjaxData),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (msg, textStatus, request) {
        console.log(msg);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to decorate the API action with `[FromBody]`, you should serialize to Json when posting the data from client side. You can use `JSON.stringify(TheAjaxData)`.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/thewebapi/themethod",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(TheAjaxData),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (msg, textStatus, request) {
        console.log(msg);
    }
});
```

Another option is removing the `[FromBody]` attribute and pass the javascript object directly. Actually, in your case `TheRequestObjectModel` just have string properties and it doesn't contain another complex object. So, It could be better to remove the `[FromBody]` attribute.

```
[Route("themethod")]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(TheRequestObjectModel TheObject)
{
    var testvalue = TheObject.Property1;
}

$.ajax({
    url: "/thewebapi/themethod",
    type: "POST",
    data: TheAjaxData,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (msg, textStatus, request) {
        console.log(msg);
    }
});
```